# Kubuntu 14.04 desktop resets unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, desktop-background, widgets

Last week I Installed Kubuntu 14.04 on my computer. Everything works fine except for a problem that happened twice so far: Every widget and wallpaper on all of my desktops disappeared after a normal boot.

I've looked in KSystemLog and found no error. Everything else is the same as before (bars, start menu, etc...) and other users' desktop did not change.

It never happened on my old install of Kubuntu (Also 14.04). I can place the widgets back, but I am looking for a permanent solution. Thanks for any help.